# Delphi Determine filesize in real time

Tags: delphi, filesize

Is it possible in Delphi to determine the size of a file as it is being copied? I get a notification when a file is first copied to a folder, but need to wait until the copy is complete before I can process the file.

I've used `JclFileUtils.GetSizeOfFile(Filename)` but that gives me the 'expected' file size, not the current filesize.

Regards, Pieter

Comment: Why not ask for the file size of the source file?

Comment: That does not tell me if the new file is complete. I want to wait while the new file size is smaller that the source file size.

Comment: Are you actually trying to ask about progress? (100 kbytes copied of a 300 megabyte file?). If so why not write the file-copy code yourself, and you can implement notifications every 100 kb or whatever you decide.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompted by the first answer I decided to give up on trying to determine when a file copy has completed. Instead I found that using `TFileStream` gave me a reliable indication whether a file is in use or not.

```
function IsFileInUse(Filename: string; var ResultMessage: string): boolean;
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := True;
  ResultMessage := '';
  try
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      Result := False;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Stream);
    end;

  Except on E: Exception do
    ResultMessage := 'IsFileInUse: ' + E.Message
  end;
end;
```

In this way I can keep on checking until the file is not in use anymore before attempting to process it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the technique that is used by the copying function. Most copy-methods will allocate the disk space first before they start to copy a file. Thus, if you want to copy a file of 4 GB, the system starts by creating a file with random data for 4 GB in total. (Which is done lightning-fast, btw.) It then copies the data itself, but the file size is already what you expect.
This has as advantage that the sysmen can check if there's enough disk space available to actually copy the data.

If you write your own file copy function then you can have total control over how it does this. Else, you're limited to whatever the chosen copy-method offers you. So, how do you copy a file?

Comment: The files are copied by remote users so it's most likely windows copy/paste. I use a foldermonitor (ReadDirectoryChangesW) to notify me of a change in a folder.

Comment: The Windows Copy/Paste will allocate diskspace before copying to guarantee there's enough space, so it won't offer you any method to see it's progress/growth...

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the file copy process, it is easiest to have the copy routine create the file using a temporary filename, and when done, rename it to correct filename.
That way, you can use Windows folder monitoring to watch for the renaming (JCL contains a component to help with this, not sure about the name from here). When your code gets triggered you are sure the other side has finished writing the file.
A simple trick I used was to have the copying process create new files with a '$$$' extension. My code still got triggered for those but I ignored them until they were renamed to their proper filename.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah. Didn't see your reply to Wim...so my solution is a no-go.

Comment: Another option might be to occasionally (timer-based) try to get an exclusive lock on the file. While the copy process is writing this is not possible. Once you can lock the file, you know the copying is finished (or aborted).

Comment: That would seem to be the most promising way to ensure that the file is complete. Thank you.